# Database : Retrieve the most recent message for all id

Tags: sql, database, select, laravel

I do an internal messaging service on my Laravel website in the same look of Facebook messaging service.

So, I want a section who assembles all conversations. For this, I want to retrieve the most recent message by user.

I tried this in my SQL request

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
                ->join('messages', 'users.id', '=' ,'messages.useridsend')
                ->select('users.name', 'users.photo', 'messages.*')
                ->where('messages.useridreceive', $id)
                ->groupby('messages.useridsend')
                ->max('messages.created_at');
```

Comment: It's a great solution, but it return juste the most recent of all my database, not for each id. Maybe because of a bad use of max(). I tried to delete the orderby() and replace get() by max('messages.created_at').

Comment: No, he's between the where() and the max(). I edit my subject to show you my new code

Comment: Using [rank()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms176102.aspx)  by might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to have a look how it's done in laravel, but in MySQL (or all RDBMS, as it's standard SQL) it works like this.

To get the minimum or maximum of a certain column you use something like

```
select min(your_column) from your_table;
```

This gets the minimum value of the column for the whole table. With

```
select another_column, min(your_column) from your_table group by another_column;
```

you get the minimum for each group. But this does not get the corresponding row values of the other columns for that group. Each group is "collapsed" and a random row of each group is displayed unless you use one of the aggregate functions. You can verify this by doing something like this:

```
select another_column, min(your_column), max(a_third_column) from your_table group by another_column;
```

So, the big question is, how to get corresponding values to a row determined by the aggregate function?

One way is to determine which row to select with the aggregate function and joining it back to the table:

```
select * from your_table 
inner join (
  select the_column_you're_grouping_by, min(maybe_a_timestamp_column) as min_ts from yourtable
) subquery_alias 
on your_table.the_column_you're_grouping_by = subquery_alias.the_column_you're_grouping_by
and your_table.maybe_a_timestamp_column = subquery_alias.min_ts
```

A better example and other examples how to do it can be found in this manual entry: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Hope it's understood now :) All you have to do now, is to translate it into laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution like your.

```
SELECT u.name,
       u.photo,
       m.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN messages m ON u.id = m.useridsend
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT useridsend,
    MAX(created_at) AS created_at
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY useridsend
) r ON m.useridsend = r.useridsend
AND m.created_at = r.created_at
WHERE m.useridreceive=2
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC;
```

Thanks for your help.